# Where are headers for Scotch and PT-Scotch located?

Tags: lubuntu, header-file

I've installed `ptscotch` with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install ptscotch
```

Then I wanted to compile the Pastix library, but it's throwing the error:

```
symbol/src/dof.c:54:22: fatal error: ptscotch.h: No such file or directory
```

So I tried to find the `ptscotch.h` file, but I found nothing. It appears that Pastix looks for it in my home folder, but there is no "scotch folder" and there is not `ptscotch.h` file in `/usr/include` or `/usr/local/include`.

So, where should I look for this file? Or is it contained in some other package in the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command, `apt-file`, is a good one to use for searching packages for a specific file name.

```
apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
apt-file search ptscotch.h
```

This produces the package name (libptscotch-dev) and the file found by the search term. Then just install the package that was found by `apt-file`:

```
apt-get install libptscotch-dev
```